# Angular External Style in Angular.json or Styles.scss

Tags: css, angular, sass, node-modules

I want to include an external style from a module in `node_modules`. Which is considered better practice?

1. Add the stylesheet to `Angular.json` in the application's `build: styles: []`, e.g.

```
"build": {
  "styles": [
      ...,
      "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
  }
}
```

2. Import the stylesheet into the application's `styles.scss` file, e.g.

```
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

If I were using `styles.css` instead of `styles.scss`, the second wouldn't work. However, given that I'm using SASS, I'm wondering if the second is preferred because it keeps `Angular.json` cleaner.

Are the two functionally equivalent or is there an important distinction that makes one better than the other?

Comment: I prefer the second option, because that allows you to override styles in a cleaner (my opinion, someone might have different opinions) way